# Returning state after API call inside getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getderivedstatefromprops

I have a react component that receives props for filtering from its parent. When the parent props change I use `getDerivedStateFromProps` in the child in the following code:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  if (props.filter === null) {
     return state;
  }

  const { name, description } = props.filter;

  ApiService.get("cards", { name: name, description: description })
    .then(response => {
      console.log("get request returned ", response.data);

      return { cards: response.data };
    }
  );
}
```

in the console the `response.data` log is the approriate array of objects. However the state does not update and the rendering function still uses the old `cards` array and not the one that was received from the `ApiService` response. How do I make it so the `cards` array updates properly so that on the next render it will show the filtered cards?

Comment: `getDerivedStateFromProps` is not meant for data fetching and I don't think you can do any async operations there:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13541#issuecomment-418101478

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is not the correct lifecycle hook for this. You'll need to put the fetching code in `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`, and use `this.setState` once the data is available.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
      cards: null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.filter !== prevProps.filter) {
      this.loadData();
    }
  }

  loadData() {
    const { name, description } = this.props.filter;

    ApiService.get("cards", { name: name, description: description })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ cards: response.data });
      });
  )

  render() {
    if (!this.state.cards) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    return (
      // some jsx using the cards
    )
  }
}
```